# What is the answer linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving the following model in R and Lingo. However, I am getting an incorrect result. Do you know where my error is?

**Model**

minimize $10,773 * gt_1 + 30,094.7 * gt_2 + 684 * def$

subject to:
$gt_1 + gt_2 + def + ghu = 1200$

$va + vt + vv  = 8607.04$

$-0.2275 * vt + ghu = 0$

$7000 \leq va \leq 12540$

$0 \leq vt \leq 6412.97$

$0 \leq ghu \leq 1458.86$

$gt_1, gt_2 \in \{0,1\}$

**Results from my implementation:**

$gt_1  =    0$
$gt_2  =    0$
$def   =    834.3984$
$ghu   =    365.6016$
$va    =    7000 $
$vt    =    1607.040  $
$vv    =    0$

Objective value = 57,0728.5

**Given solution:**

$gt_1  =    1 $
$gt_2   =   1   $
$def     =  20.4  $
$ghu      = 365.6  $
$va     =   7000    $
$vt    =    1607.04  $
$vv    =    0$

Objective value = 54,820.21

Comment: What is the domain of the variables $def$ and $vv$? (E.g., can they take on any value; are they constrained to be non-negative?)

Comment: 0 <= vv < Inf and 0<= def.

Answer (score 3):

When I implemented the model (using AMPL/CPLEX), I got the same results as you did.

However, note that the given solution is not feasible for the given model. E.g., for the first constraint ($gt_1+gt_2+def+ghu = 1200$), the sum of the variables from the given solution is $388$, not $1200$ as required. This tells us that either the given model is wrong or the given solution is wrong.